# How to define args inside a .travis.yml?

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I have the following `.travis.yml` file to deploy my project on [`Travis CI`](http://travis-ci.org):

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 'lts/*'
  - 'node'
  - '8'

before_install:
# package-lock.json was introduced in npm@5
  - '[[ $(node -v) =~ ^v9.*$ ]] || npm install -g npm@latest' # skipped when using node 9
  - npm install -g greenkeeper-lockfile@1
install: npm install
before_script: greenkeeper-lockfile-update
after_script: greenkeeper-lockfile-upload
after_success: npm run coverage
deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: sorackb@gmail.com
  api_key: $NPM_TOKEN
  on:
    tags: true
```

And I need to pass the [`--tls-min-v1.0`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_default_min_version) argument to `node_js` `lts/` and `node`. Can I do that in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify your argument through the environment variable [NODE_OPTIONS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options)

```
language: node_js

env:
  global:
    - NODE_OPTIONS="--tls-min-v1.0"

node_js:
  - 'lts/*'
  - 'node'
  - '8'

before_install:
# package-lock.json was introduced in npm@5
  - '[[ $(node -v) =~ ^v9.*$ ]] || npm install -g npm@latest' # skipped when using node 9
  - npm install -g greenkeeper-lockfile@1
install: npm install
before_script: greenkeeper-lockfile-update
after_script: greenkeeper-lockfile-upload
after_success: npm run coverage
deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: sorackb@gmail.com
  api_key: $NPM_TOKEN
  on:
    tags: true
```